# Cannot get Download Handler to overwrite files with the same name correctly

Tags: r, shiny

When using Download Handler in a shiny App if I am trying to download a data table with 33 lines to a csv file, this works fine. Problems start occurring if I then then try and alter the data table in the code to be only two rows long and yet want to save the file under the same name and overwrite the old file. I find that the top two lines are overwritten, but the old data is still there below the 2 new lines. It hasn't increased the number of lines but it hasn't decreased them either.

I have already tried looking to delete the existing file but download handler appears to use temporary files. I have also tried write.csv(data, file, append="false") but this doesn't work either, likely for the same reason. Has anyone come up with a solution to this? Below is a working reproducible code.

```
 {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    downloadLink("downloadData", "Download")
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
    # Our dataset
    data <- mtcars #I change this on my second save to mtcars[3:4,]

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(data, file)

      }
    )
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

What I expect to see is a csv file with the same number of lines as the current table regardless of the previous file size. Thank you for your help!

Comment: what code do you use to change it to `mtcars[3:4,]`?

Comment: I just manually alter the original code and rerun the app. This should overwrite the file.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue - it completely overwrites the file and only shows 2 lines of output when I run your code on my machine. Does your machine prompt you with a save option or does it automatically download the file?

Comment: It asks me if I would like to overwrite the file, I click yes but it does not overwrite anything except the top two lines. It must be how the program is configured on my system then if you cannot reproduce the error. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post an image of the dialog box asking if you would like to overwrite?